# Beautify hyperlink using urlrewriterfilter

Tags: java, url, redirect

I'm trying to redirect from one URL to another one using `urlrewriterfilter`

```
<rule>
<from>/abc</from>
<to type="redirect">http://google.com</to>
</rule>
```

I run my program from localhost, and the problem is that I don't know why it generated a hyperlink that looks like this: `http://127.0.0.1http://google.com`

Answer (score 0):

Try moving this rule to the top of the rule chain and adding the "last" attribute.

^/abc
http://google.com

Comment: it didn't work. do you know how to remove the context-path from the generated to url

Comment: I still think other parts of the rule chain might be messing you up, edited my answer.